How to solve a system of XOR equations in a cyclic graph?
I am working on a problem where I need to find values for nodes in a graph of k-nodes. Here an example:

The properties are:

Each big node (A..H) is connected to at least one blue node
Each blue node has exactly 3 edges
The value of each blue node equals the XOR of each connected node.

For this specific case, we have:
0 = A ⊕ B ⊕ C
1 = B ⊕ D ⊕ E
2 = C ⊕ F ⊕ G
3 = B ⊕ C ⊕ D
4 = G ⊕ F ⊕ H
5 = D ⊕ E ⊕ G

I am trying to find if there is a solution. Bruteforce is obviously not a solution :(

As I'm sure you're aware, XOR-SAT is solvable efficiently.

Not sure what it means to XOR values and get more than 1 though. Are these bitvectors?

@cody It's an XOR operation on a whole binary number, rather than just on single bit.
Imagine 3 XOR 5. Convert to binary: 011 XOR 101 = 110.
You just apply XOR to each bit 1-by-1, in-line.
So XOR first bit in both numbers. XOR second bit, XOR third bit... and so on

You can express this as an instance of XOR-SAT, then find a solution using Gaussian elimination.  I am assuming that each value $1,2,3,$ represents a bit-vector of some appropriate length, and you are doing bitwise XOR.  The variables are the individual bits of $A,B,C,\dots$, and each equation yields one clause per bit position.

It was exactly what I was looking for, however the performances are not what I was expected (https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/168079/34863)
